# How to Create Start-Up Disk for 12.04 without Ubuntu Software Center (broken) using Dell Inspiron Mini

Tags: 12.04, software-center, startup

I messed with some (okay, many) codes in terminal trying to work on another issue. (Copying and pasting from other posts here.)

Now Ubuntu Software Center is not working at all.  It closes and tells me Ubuntu 12.04 has an internal error but can not determine what it is.

I used [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133456/can-i-uninstall-and-reinstall-ubuntu-software-center) to uninstall and reinstall Ubuntu Software Center.  It did not change anything.

**What I want more than anything in the world** right now is to **completely wipe out my current 12.04 and reinstall it fresh**.  I have made back ups of my files.  I have the 12.04 desktop iso on my flashdrive, I know that it is my #2 key on my computer to kick it into the boot device (I use a Dell Inspiron Mini which has no F12).

But it is not working.

I think someplace I read about needing to Create A Start Up Disk but I am having a hard time finding a explanation simple enough for a 3 year old to follow that will help me do this WITHOUT the SOFTWARE CENTER which will not even open up.

PLEASE HELP.  I just want my computer back and am so incredibly frustrated.

Comment: have you tried to fix broken packages? it may get the software center working again... in terminal enter "sudo apt-get install -f"

Comment: This is what I get when I do the "sudo apt-get-instal-f"

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: will the software center open now?

Comment: It does the same.  The box opens for about 5 seconds and then closes and goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to create a startup disk (USB) from Windows 7

- Insert your flash drive into the Win 7 computer, and **copy the ISO you already have** to somewhere on your hard disk (e.g. *My Documents*). Also copy any backups, etc. on the flash drive because turning it into a startup disk will **wipe all existing data off it**.
- Simply download and run [UNetBootin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/files/UNetbootin/575/unetbootin-windows-575.exe/download) in Windows 7 (note: the link will take you to a direct download).
- Point UNetBootin to the ISO you saved *(Diskimage:)*, and to your flash drive letter (type must be *"USB Drive"*. Click OK to create the disk...wait for it to complete, and you're done!

  [image]

Comment: I have the iso for 12.04 on my ext hd and my flash drive I have emptied.   Will that be sufficient?  After I get my kids to bed I will do the steps above using my Windows machine and my flash drive.    THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: Yes, just connect both to your Windows machine and use the `...` button to point Unetbootin to the ISO. *But be sure* to select the correct drive letter for the flash drive (since two external drives will be connected...). Good luck and please post back if you have any problems! :)

Comment: Clicking the UNetBootin above downloaded a 4.6MB .exe file.  It never asked me where to save it and my Windows computer is now asking me if I want to make changes to the computer when I double click it in the Downloads to open it up.   I'm not wanting my Windows computer changed.  Do I want to "let it make changes" anyway or is something wrong?  When I clicked the UNetBootin link it gave me an option to *save* or *cancel* but no *save to* option.  The last thing I want is for two computers to be messed up.  Thank you for your advisement. :)

Comment: Yes, allow it to make changes -- that simply gives it the right to format the USB drive to prepare it as a boot disk. It won't damage your computer :)

Comment: It installed wonderfully.  Thank you.  Need to now remember how to get all the little necessities (getting wireless and printer to be recognized) accomplished but I think I can handle that.  :)  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you check my comments above you may be able to fix your software center.

As to your question, if you just copied the files to your flashdrive and did not use a start up disk creator it will not be bootable.  Here is a link to Ubuntu's website that is easy to follow and will use a program that should already be on your computer(unless you have removed it) called "Start Up Disk Creator" it will allow you to get a bootable iso on your flashdrive.  Then you should be able to install from it just select the option to replace Ubuntu on the install screen.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

If after this you can select the usb drive but get some errors booting into it, you might need to edit the title of your question to include your computer model, you might get an answer from someone that knows your particular model and can give you very specific help.

Comment: That is the problem that I am dealing with.  I can not get Ubuntu Software Center to run, therefore I can not create a Start Up Disk.   Uninstalling and reinstalling Ubunutu Software center using the codes in the above post did not fix my Software center.

So, is there a way to put the Start up Disk on my flash drive w/o Ubuntu Software Center (I have a Windows 7 system that I could use).

Without using Ubuntu Software Center HOW can I create the software disk onto my flash drive?

Comment: you should not need the software center if you have the program already installed.  Open your dash and start typing Startup Disk Creator. An icon should pop up that you can click to start the program.  You can then follow the directions to use the program.  The shortcut to open you dash is your "Windows" key(Called Super[key] in Linux)

Comment: A long time ago I changed it to the Classic View.  I don't know how to access the dash.  Can you advise where I might search?

Comment: Hitting the windows button alone doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: if by classic you mean Gnome Classic, it should be System Tools>Administration.  in a terminal you could also type  usb-creator-gtk

Comment: I'm confused by your statement, "hitting windows button alone..."  could you please clarify

Comment: Hitting windows button alone = You mentioned pressing the "Windows" key would open the dash.  When I press the Windows key it does nothing.  Yes, I think I meant Gnome Classic.   I have tried the type usb-creator-gtk with no avail.  After I get my little kids to bed I will create a start-up-disk using my Windows 7 machine.  :)  I'm pretty convinced a total un-install-re-install is my best option at the moment.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Windows key is only a shortcut in Unity.  It would appear that whatever you did really fragged your system.  If you want to save your important files and then reinstall, you best bet might be to use your  Windows computer and use the other answer that tells you how to Make a start up disk with Windows.  I have never used the program mentioned but it seems easy enough.