# Ubuntu Software Centre is gone! How can I get it back?

Tags: 12.04, apt, software-center, package-management

Right. I am having MAJOR issues. (It would be much appreciated if you would solve them for me! Check my profile for open questions...)

Following an answerer... who sorry to say... didn't give a great answer because it was just a graphical way of doing what I had already done - suggested I purge a library.
Turns out that library controlled the Advanced Packaging Tool (apt), Ubuntu Software Centre and the repositories. Not a great tool to mess with.

While trying to purge the library, it came up with 'Removing MyUnity.. Removing x... Removing x... Removing Ubuntu Software Centre... Removing X... Removing apt..."
I quickly recognized and force shut-down my system. But I guess it was too late.

So... well, plainly put - how do I get it back?!

Comment: I suggest you backup your data and reinstall Ubuntu from scratch

Comment: @kamil, I am seriously considering that. However, I think I'll wait until 12.10 and do a fresh install of that. Jokerdino, thanks for your offer. Sorry I wasn't available at that time ;) Cheers to both of you

Comment: give my below answer a try

Comment: Please view the comment I left on your answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope apt-get is still installed. Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run this command :

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

In case Synaptic Package Manager is still running Search for Ubuntu Software Center and install it from there.

I think [**this post**](https://askubuntu.com/q/133456/91632) will let you learn how to uninstall/install software center.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to perform this due to my 'problem' (http://askubuntu.com/questions/196985/dependencies-not-met-on-12-04) which leaves the Packaging Tool/APT library completely useless. So I'm unable to do anything until that is solved. However, this is a very valid answer to those without screwed-up systems and will be accepted. Cheers and thanks for the consideration.

Comment: Thank you, that is much appreciated. I think I have ...-uped my system even more trying to fix it...