# Ubuntu Software Center doesn't lauch/uninstall [12.10]

Tags: software-center

This cropped up somewhere during the process of installing an nvidia driver (310.32) for my graphic card.
Whenever I clicked on the Ubuntu Software Center icon on the launcher, it seemed to work (animation on icon to show that it was starting), and then nothing. 
So I did the first stupid thing, I tried to remove and reinstall the Software Center; apparently, the remove didn't work properly, so I tried again. Here's the terminal session:

```
parth@Gladoss:~$ sudo apt-get remove software-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  software-center
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 304 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 4,485 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 176079 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing software-center ...
dpkg: error processing software-center (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/usr/share/app-install/menu.d/featured.menu': Not a directory
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 software-center
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
parth@Gladoss:~$
```

Let me know how I can properly remove and reinstall the program.
Thanks.

EDIT:
command sudo apt-get update comes to a stop with error message (terminal)

---

W: GPG error: ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4F191A5A8844C542

---

EDIT:
Tried the commands:
(i)sudo rm /usr/share/app-install/menu.d/featured.menu
result : directory does not exist.
(ii)sudo rm -rf /usr/share/app-install/menu.d/featured.menu
result : nothing. Terminal just gets ready to accept new line.
Further, I tried "sudo apt-get install software-center". Same error message as original post.

EDIT:
sudo apt-get --reinstall install software-center returns

---

(Reading database ... 176080 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace software-center 5.4.1.2 (using .../software-center_5.4.1.4_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement software-center ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/software-center_5.4.1.4_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/app-install/desktop', which is also in package app-install-data-partner 12.12.10
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 **/var/cache/apt/archives/software-center_5.4.1.4_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)**

---

EDIT :
I figured something was wrong with the dpkg, I googled that.
Some commands I tried afterwards.

---

parth@Gladoss:~$ sudo dpkg --audit
The following packages are only half installed, due to problems during
installation.  The installation can probably be completed by retrying it;
the packages can be removed using dselect or dpkg --remove:
 software-center      Utility for browsing, installing, and removing software

---

---

parth@Gladoss:~$ sudo dpkg --remove software-center
(Reading database ... 176079 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing software-center ...
dpkg: error processing software-center (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/usr/share/app-install/menu.d/featured.menu': Not a directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 software-center

---

[In succession]

EDIT :
sudo dpkg -L software-center
brings up a whole lot of files; including /usr/share/app-install/menu.d/featured.menu
If it's being shown here, how is it that a recursive force remove ignores it? Are their any other commands (not related to rm) which might work?

Answer (score 0):

Remove manually

> /usr/share/app-install/menu.d/featured.menu

```
sudo rm /usr/share/app-install/menu.d/featured.menu
```

Then try and reinstall Software Center

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install software-center
```

Comment: terminal***parth@Gladoss:~$ sudo rm /usr/share/app-install/menu.d/featured.menu
rm: cannot remove `/usr/share/app-install/menu.d/featured.menu': Not a directory
***

Comment: Here is the menu.d file's text, if it helps *** [Desktop Entry]
X-AppInstall-Package=noiz2sa
X-AppInstall-Popcon=11
X-AppInstall-Section=universe

Type=Application
Name=Noiz2sa
Comment=An Abstract Shooter by Kenta Cho
Icon=noiz2sa
Exec=/usr/games/noiz2sa
Terminal=false
Categories=Game;ArcadeGame;

X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=app-install-data***

Comment: Try sudo rm -rf instead

Comment: Can you please put this information in your question? It's hard to understand what part is broken if you put the information we need in the comments buried down here and out of context!

Comment: Sorry. Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from another thread - ([Can I uninstall and reinstall Ubuntu Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133456/can-i-uninstall-and-reinstall-ubuntu-software-center))

You've done step one of the top answer, now try the three other steps:

1. `sudo apt-get autoremove software-center`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install software-center`

The alternative is in Eliah Kagans answer

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install software-center`

Hopefully the previous thread can help more with this.

Comment: sorry, I'm getting the same error message.

Comment: Did you try both methods? Including the alternative from Eliah Kagans answer?

Comment: yes. I'm also getting an error message after the update command. ***W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4F191A5A8844C542
***

Comment: The GPG error is fine, its because you have installed some third party softwares and the system is not able to verify the identity of the authors of the software. Don't worry too much about it, you can probably trust them.