# trouble downloading software from software center

Tags: software-center

after installng 12.04 LTS version through wubi ,i am unable to install softwares from software center.It shows the message to check internet connection,but i am able to load pages from mozila.i tried to change software source from main server to my country but it  is not showning any server from my country ,help please

Comment: can you please post the last few lines of the result from the following command:
sudo apt-get update

Comment: Try the solution described [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133456/can-i-uninstall-and-reinstall-ubuntu-software-center)