# The Software Center will open but will not respond

Tags: 12.04, software-center

I am using 12.04 and have only recently started using Ubuntu. I am very confused and would appreciate the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is rather a suggestion, but if there is something wrong and you possess little knowledge on Ubuntu/Debian/Linux yet, a good approach could be

1. Back up your data (this is always good, so that nothing can get lost).
2. Use the way outlined in this answer: [Can I uninstall and reinstall Ubuntu Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/a/133473/91669) (I copied the information and pasted it below).

   What will be the attempt to "repair your Software Center malfunction", is to un-install and the re-install it. By doing so, a lot of other software should also be uninstalled and reinstalled and it seemed to work in the answer linked. Here is the recipie:

Press  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>  simultaneously to enter terminal.

**To uninstall Software Center:**

1. `sudo apt-get remove software-center`
2. `sudo apt-get autoremove software-center`

**To re-install Software Center:**

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install software-center`