# 'Install' option is missing in ubuntu software center

Tags: software-center

I am new with linux. Recently I installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS (x64 bit). When trying to install software from **Ubuntu Software Center**, the <kbd>Install</kbd> button on right is missing.

Also, when I am trying to install **CompizConfig Setting Manager**, instead of <kbd>Install</kbd> button there is <kbd>Use this source</kbd> button.

Please help me how can i download.

It was working fine when i installed it on Wubi (Ubuntu 32 bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is common to new installation of Ubuntu 12.04 (I haven't checked any other versions of Ubuntu). Just make a update after installation of Ubuntu. This will install all required repositories and the `use this source` is removed by `install`.

Use following `sudo` code to perform update

> sudo apt-get update

Answer (score 2):

Now all is working fine...
There was something locking administrator, I just removed it out by

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

and also deleted the **lock** file in the cache directory

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

After that all is fine...

Answer (score 0):

The PPA is inside the **source**. You have to add the source, then you can install the PPA.

After you press <kbd>Use this source</kbd>, the Software Center will install the source, and then the <kbd>Install</kbd> button will appear instead.

Comment: But this was not happening when i was using 32 bit of ubuntu 12.04 LTS. why this is happening so. i am using a low speed internet so cannot download huge files.

Comment: I am not really certain why you got this issue after changing to another OS (from **Ubuntu 12.04 x32** to **Ubuntu 12.04 x64**), but as far as I know - this is how one installs PPAs on Linux. First, you need to have **source**, update it and then **install** the PPA (this way not only via Software Center). I am more curious why you didn't had to do this on your previous version. *And sources are not really big thing to be downloaded.*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for weeks. i couldn't fix it using suggested things.i followed these.
Did you use any other network with your computer? because i got this problem after i used my university network.
if so, please go to

System Setting -> Network -> Network Proxy and change them it to your home proxy setting and apply system wide.

restart and check software center or updating functions.

Answer (score -1):

Consider removing and re-installing Software Center. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, the terminal opens.

Here's how you can remove and re-install Software Center: [Can I uninstall and reinstall Ubuntu Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133456/can-i-uninstall-and-reinstall-ubuntu-software-center)

Synaptic Package Manager is another faster and better alternative to Ubuntu Software Center.
To get it, type in terminal:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install synaptic`

Comment: You don't need to reinstall Software Center to get the **Install** button instead of **Use this source** button.