# Cant download from Ubuntu Software centre

Tags: software-center, repository

I cant download anything from Ubuntu software center, it hangs on updating cache then its telling me "failed to download repository information". Linux I understand suppose to be a straight forward OS with no hiccups, but lately its been giving me headaches and I just only installed it 5 days ago. I looked up similar problems but nothing comes close to fixing it. Any suggestions or fixes ?

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using? Can you copy the content of the file `/etc/apt/source.list`?

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> simultaneously to enter a terminal.

**To uninstall Software Center:**

```
sudo apt-get remove software-center
```

Followed by:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove software-center
```

**To re-install Software Center:**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Followed by:

`sudo apt-get install software-center`

*Found this answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133456/can-i-uninstall-and-reinstall-ubuntu-software-center).*

Comment: after trying the last bit "Sudo apt-get install software-center" i got this message on terminal "package 'software-center' has no installation candidate

Comment: Post the result of `sudo software-center` in your question pleas.