# How do I install Ubuntu Software Centre application?

Tags: software-installation, software-center

I accidentally removed the Ubuntu Software Centre, when I was actually trying to remove my Ubuntu One applications. Although I don't remember directly uninstalling the Centre, I think deleting one of those packages might have triggered it.

I cannot look at history of application changes, as the Software Centre is missing.

Please advise on how to install, or rather reinstall, Ubuntu Software Centre on my computer.

Comment: I removed your mention of 13.10. While that information shouldn't make any difference, it prompted someone to vote to close the question, since that release is no longer supported.

Comment: Related: [Can I uninstall and reinstall Ubuntu Software Center?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133456/can-i-uninstall-and-reinstall-ubuntu-software-center)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are not sure what you deleted, I suggest you to run `sudo apt-get purge software-center` to clear all files it left over. Then, you can reinstall from scratch by running `sudo apt-get install software-center`.

Regarding the history of changes, there is a log file called .bash_history in your home folder which show the history of the commands you run in the terminal. This is a hidden file so in order to see it you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. This can give you hints of what you deleted.

Comment: I've already downloaded it, is there a way I can still purge any useless files?

Comment: I'm not sure about that but it is always safe to uninstall (via purge) and then reinstall.

Comment: You mean now that I have it installed, I should run these: `purge software-center` and `install software-center`? Isn't it already installed? Where's any reinstall or uninstall happening?

Answer (score 1):

You could try running:

`sudo apt-get install software-center`