# When i open ubuntu software center , it automatically closes within seconds. why?

Tags: software-center

I even tried opening it through terminal, it does the same thing.

[image]

Comment: try to run it with sudo? it seems you got a problem with interference with you user account.

Comment: i tried now.  the same thing happens.. it opens and then closes...

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Software Center?

Comment: no. how to do that. i am a new user. pls tell

Comment: try uninstalling and installing again? maybe this will help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/133456/can-i-uninstall-and-reinstall-ubuntu-software-center @T.AnanthaBoudmanabhan

Comment: it didn't work neither brother.. what to do?

Comment: open up a terminal and run this command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libwebkitgtk-3.0-0` and try to start Software Center from terminal again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Software Center failed to Load a shared library `libwedkitgtk-3.0.so.0`

reinstall it by opening up a terminal and running the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
```

and try to start Software Center again.