# Software Center Is Missing And I Can't Reinstall It

Tags: software-center

As the title says my software center is missing and I can not reinstall it. When I try to reinstall it I get the following message.

```
nickanthony@nickanthony-Aspire-E5-511:~$ sudo apt-get install software-center
[sudo] password for nickanthony: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate
```

As you can see I have an Acer Aspire E5-511. I currently have Ubuntu 14.10 installed and running as the only operating system.

Please help if you can. Thank you kindly.

Comment: I think you have your answer here http://askubuntu.com/questions/133456/can-i-uninstall-and-reinstall-ubuntu-software-center

Comment: 14.10 has reached End of Life (as of  July 23, 2015 ). I'd suggest you upgrade to newer version. But if you insist on keeping 14.10 and still installing software center ,  go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/software-center and download tarball (tar.gz) file for it and install manually