# Software center doesn't open when i click its icon!

Tags: software-sources

When i click the software center icon it blinks but doesnot open.
Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: Run `gnome-software` in terminal and see if it will open.

Comment: It didn't worked for me!

Comment: Did it show any errors? Also which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: it didn't and i'm using 16.04

Comment: Try to [Uninstall and reinstall Ubuntu Software Center](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133456/can-i-uninstall-and-reinstall-ubuntu-software-center/133473#133473).

Comment: Try once sudo apt-get update and check.

Answer (score -2):

Try to restart the system and open the software center again. But I sure recomenda that you use the command line to make stuff on Linux Systens