# mysql doesn't uninstall

Tags: package-management, mysql, dependencies, software-uninstall

I want to reinstall mysql in Ubuntu 16.04.

```
mysql-server is already the newest version (5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

After this I wrote a code for removing mysql, but it's not being removed.

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.1' for glob 'mysql-server-core-*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.5' for glob 'mysql-server-core-*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.6' for glob 'mysql-server-core-*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.7' for glob 'mysql-server-core-*'
Package 'mysql-server-core-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-core-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-core-5.1' is not installed, so not removed
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.5' for glob 'mysql-client-core-*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.6' for glob 'mysql-client-core-*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.7' for glob 'mysql-client-core-*'
Package 'mysql-client-core-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client-core-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient20 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5) but it is not going to be installed
 mariadb-common : Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.6.25) but it is not going to be installed
 mysql-client-5.7 : Depends: mysql-client-core-5.7 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Please add what the first command you ran is.

Comment: Have you tried its suggestion `sudo apt -f install`?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I uninstall and reinstall Ubuntu Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133456/can-i-uninstall-and-reinstall-ubuntu-software-center) Specifically I think you need to use [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/171247/225694) on the package in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps:

1. This removes `mysql-server` from your System.

   ```
   apt-get autoremove mysql-server
   ```
2. Check if you still have `mysql` installed.

   ```
   mysql -V
   ```
3. This installs mysql-server

   ```
   apt-get install mysql-server
   ```

If you are still having having issues start with

```
apt-get install -f
```

If it still does not work try:

```
dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server
```